# How merge PDF with python, and make it run even if some file is missing?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pdf

I have a folder full of PDF's and i have to merge some of them in an specific order so i have created a really long code (really bad optimized but it should do the work)

```
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger

pdfs = ['Base.pdf','1.pdf']
  merger = PdfFileMerger()
  for pdf in pdfs:
  merger.append(pdf)
  merger.write("Result_1.pdf")
  merger.close()

pdfs = ['Base.pdf','1.pdf','2.pdf']
    merger = PdfFileMerger()
    for pdf in pdfs:
    merger.append(pdf)
    merger.write("Result_2.pdf")
    merger.close()
```

[And the code repeats 120 times, with differents combinnations.]

I may miss some files so the code stops whenever it found a missing file.

I think it may include something thet stop the code whenever some pdf is missing and restart in the next line of code, and maybe print an error message.

Answer (score 2):

If a file is missing, you get a `FileNotFoundError`. You can catch this exception and continue like this:

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger

pdfs = ['Base.pdf','1.pdf', 'missing.pdf', '2.pdf'] 
merger = PdfFileMerger()

for pdf in pdfs:
    try:
        merger.append(pdf)
    except FileNotFoundError:
        print("Skipping file %s" % pdf)

merger.write("Result_1.pdf")
merger.close()
```

And if you want to clean up your code, put the pdf merging into a function:

```py
from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger

def merge_pdfs(pdfs, merged_file):
    merger = PdfFileMerger()
    for pdf in pdfs:
        try:
            print("Merging file %s" % pdf)
            merger.append(pdf)
        except FileNotFoundError:
            print("Skipping file %s" % pdf)
    print("Writing result file")
    merger.write(merged_file)
    merger.close()


pdfs = ['Base.pdf','1.pdf'] 
merge_pdfs(pdfs, "Result1.pdf")

pdfs = ['Base.pdf','1.pdf','2.pdf']
merge_pdfs(pdfs, "Result2.pdf")
```

Comment: Hi, I have tried it with all the files and with just 2 files and I can't get the merged files neither the error print.

`from PyPDF2 import PdfFileMerger`
`def merge_pdfs(pdfs, merged_file):`
`merger = PdfFileMerger()`
`for pdf in pdfs:`
`try:`
`merger.append(pdf)`
`except FileNotFoundError:`
`print("Skipping file %s" % pdf)`
`merger.write(merged_file)`
`merger.close()`

`pdfs = ['Base_DUP.pdf','08102A00800106.pdf','08102A00800107.pdf']`
`merge_pdfs(pdfs,"1_Resultado.pdf")`

`pdfs = ['Base_DUP.pdf','08102A00800107.pdf']`
`merge_pdfs(pdfs,"2_Resultado.pdf")`

Comment: @SSD93 Here it works. I have added some debugging code to the function. Please double check the correct indentation and try again.

Comment: I think my problem is with the PDFs format, because i have tried my old code in the pdfs i have and it dosen't work the way it worked with my example pdfs

Answer (score 1):

What about check if the file exists before merging?

```
import os.path

def filter_pdf(files):
    for pdf_file in files:
        if os.path.isfile(pdf_file):
            yield pdf_file
```